# How to make logical inference from simulation generated data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability, inference

I have data collected from a computer simulation of football games which seem to have recurring patterns of the following form.

*if madrid plays arsernal and the match ends under 3 goal, then on their next match against each others, madrid will win. if madrid happens to loose and then plays against chelsea next, they will win 90% of the time.*

how do I find such inferences from simulation generated data like this. There are other forms of hidden patterns that I believe exists in the dataset.

Comment: This question is probably better off on the Data Science site as it's more theoretical than programming: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/